# Compare two Excell, finally merge into a new one in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two Excell.
The first one is:comapre.xlsx https://www.dropbox.com/s/xem8b4ce9xd6rx0/compare.xlsx?dl=0
The second one is:main.xlsx https://www.dropbox.com/s/3i909pu76dbspdo/main.xlsx?dl=0

What I want to do is to compare the value in column A of the main.xlsx with the value in column A of Comapare.xlsx.
If it matches, write the other columns of comapre.xlsx and column A together into the third Excell:link.xlsx, and if it doesn't match, connect the two values that don't match with "->", like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/535t2c4pnhbeskj/link.xlsx?dl= 0

I Google to find the method is to use Pandas like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path = r"D:\x\Python_Study\Excell\\"
df1=pd.read_excel(path+'compare.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel(path+'main.xlsx')
df1.equals(df2)
comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
print (comparison_values)
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)
for item in zip(rows,cols):
    df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0],item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])     
df1.to_excel('link.xlsx',index=False,header=True)
```

REF:https://kanoki.org/2019/02/26/compare-two-excel-files-for-difference-using-python/

But it will report an error.

**d:\x\Python_Study\Excell\test0413.py:7: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\x\Python_Study\Excell\test0413.py", line 9, in 
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

Which direction should I go? Or is there a better way to do it?
I can describe it more clearly if needed

Tks.

Comment: Add that the number of rows in the two EXCELLs are not equal

Comment: If not equal number of rows, what is logic for compare? If first file has 20 rows, second 10 rows, need compare first 10 from first file with second file? Or logic is different and need match by some column?